# Setting a property from promise in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have this ES6 class, which fails when `this.categories = data.data` is executed with the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'categories' of undefined`.

I think it is due to `this` refering to the context inside the promise.

How do I set the `this.categories` from inside the promise?

Thanks.

```
class NavbarController {
    constructor(bnCategoryService) {
        this.categories = [];    // This is what should be set with data.data.
        this.bnCategoryService = bnCategoryService;
        this.getCategories();
    }

    getCategories() {
        this.bnCategoryService.getCategories()  // Returns a promise
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data.data);
                this.categories = data.data;    // This fails!
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('Category service: An error occured getting tags from the server.');
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `.success`? what API is that? and why did you tag ES6?

Comment: (1) .success is a promise from a $http angular object, (2) the API is my websites api where data.data is an array of music tracks, (3) It's a class, therefore it uses ES6-syntax

Comment: `success` is just a sugar for `then` with some http-response pre-parsing

Comment: @skovmand, you just don't understand how `this` works. You should cache it `var that = this;` or use `arrow functions`: `(data) => {this.categories = data.data;}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use an arrow function in your success handler to get lexical `this` binding:

```
.success((data, status, headers, config) => {
  console.log(data.data);
  this.categories = data.data;    // This won't fail!
})
```

Comment: Beautiful. I didn't know the arrow function entails a lexical ```this```-binding.

Comment: Found this for reference: http://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/

Answer (score 2):

Even when your code implements an ECMA-Script 6 *class*, it doesn't mean that `this` keyword still has different meanings depending on scope.

Inside the `success` handler, `this` won't be your current class instance.

Refactor the whole code to declare a variable before calling the asynchronous operation which will hold the `this` value, and later use in the `success` handler the whole variable:

```
// This variable holds the "this" value from the class function scope.
var that = this;
this.bnCategoryService.getCategories()  // Returns a promise
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data.data);
                that.categories = data.data;    // This fails!
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('Category service: An error occured getting tags from the server.');
            });
```

Comment: This would work as well, however the arrow functions provide a more elegant solution in ES6.

Comment: @skovmand of course. I was addressing your issue *as is* so you could understand what was wrong.